# CSS Animation skip

Tags: css, animation

Here is my CSS Code:

```
#case {
    background-position: -0px 0px;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 5s;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0% {background-position: -0px 0px;}
    25% {background-position: -1050px 0px;}
    50% {background-position: -0px 0px;}
    75% {background-position: -1050px 0px;}
    100% {background-position: -1050px 0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0% {background-position: -0px 0px;}
    25% {background-position: -1050px 0px;}
    50% {background-position: -0px 0px;}
    75% {background-position: -1050px 0px;}
    100% {background-position: -1050px 0px;}
}
```

And what I need is for the animation to play through, without returning to the first keyframe on completion.

Comment: Would you mind turning it into a [code snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#case {
    background-position: -0px 0px;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 5s;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0% {background-position: -0px 0px;}
    100% {background-position: -1050px 0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0% {background-position: -0px 0px;}
    100% {background-position: -1050px 0px;}
}
```

Comment: This is work, but is not what I want, I wanna do this multiple. This same thing like 2-3x fluently

Comment: Add `animation-iteration-count: 3;` to `#case`. It will work.

Comment: Yeah this is what I want, Iˇm also try it with infinite but it not fluently. Its look that the animation stop a start again :/

Comment: "So background-position will be -1150 and after jump to 0, without retturning (just skip to 0px)." It is clear, that it will look like it starts over and over again. Tell me exactly what do you want to make.

Comment: No it dont, because here is the video of my first code turning back, and you can see -0 is equals to 4 on background and -1150 is too equals to 4 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vi_6lwzDiY8

Answer (score 0):

Youre looking for [animation-fill-mode](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp), specifically set to `forwards`.

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```